# How can I stop Document Viewer from always opening full-screen?

Tags: window, fullscreen, evince

Every time I open a PDF, Document Viewer takes up the whole screen and then I press <kbd>F11</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Up</kbd> to maximize it instead. This is tedious.

How can I stop it from automatically entering full-screen mode?

Comment: In the upper left corner there is a settings icon. Try clicking it and selecting "Save current as default" after you have gone through the process you describe.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Converting [Volodya's](https://askubuntu.com/questions/400143/how-can-i-stop-document-viewer-from-always-opening-full-screen#comment513259_400143) [answer as a comment](https://meta.askubuntu.com/a/3314) to a complete answer:

> You probably changed Document Viewer's default settings by accident. This is an easy mistake to make, since the keyboard shortcut for doing so is the same as for opening a tab in your web browser, and you frequently type into the wrong window as a result of the lag in Unity's window switcher.
>
> To correct the mistake:
>
> 1. [Exit the full-screen view](https://help.gnome.org/users/evince/stable/movingaround.html.en#zoom) by pressing <kbd>F11</kbd> or unchecking **View ▸ Fullscreen**.
> 2. [Save the current settings as default](https://help.gnome.org/users/evince/stable/default-setting.html.en) by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> or selecting **Edit ▸ Save Current Settings as Default**.
>
>    [image]
>
> This won't affect documents you've opened previously until you [reset the stored settings](https://askubuntu.com/q/400178) for those documents.

Answer (score 0):

You can also run the following command in the terminal to change the default setting:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.Evince.Default fullscreen false
```

If you also want to have all windows *maximized* by default, additionally run the following command, replacing `1920, 1080` with your screen size:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.Evince.Default window-ratio '(1920, 1080)'
```

After the first launch of Evince after that, it rewrites that ratio to something else (that still works).

(Tested on Ubuntu 20.04 with Evince 3.36.10.)